# Windows azure says "This web site is running Python 3.6.6" in Flask. what is the problem?

Tags: python, azure

I hosted the a Python Flask sample in Windows Azure. Project contains one python(*application.py*) file which contains following code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Index!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And it is set Python version as 3.6. However, why trying to open the Web URL it says following text not displaying "Index!" as message from Flask:

"This web site is running Python 3.6.6"

What could be the problem?

Comment: did you add the [ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py](https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py) to your site, so python works with iis in the webapp?

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your web.config and wfastcgi.py? if not this is an example:

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="main.app"/>
<add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\repository"/>
<add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
<add key="WSGI_RESTART_FILE_REGEX" value="" />
 </appSettings>
 <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python364x86\python.exe|D:\home\Python364x86\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```